# Electric field evaluation in electrostatics and electrodynamics

Tags: electromagnetism, electrostatics, electromagnetic-radiation, electric-fields, potential

it is known that an electrostatic field may be expressed in the following way (where r expresses the position of observation):

$E(r) = -\nabla \Phi(r)$

where $\Phi$ is the electrostatic potential. So, if we want to evaluate the voltage between two point of space, it is sufficient to know the electrostatic field between those two points, which depends only on the charge distribution in space (for instance it may be a single charge, a dipole, a sheet of charge etc).

Now let's consider an electrodynamic problem, in which we may write, in frequency domain:

$E(r) = -\nabla \Phi(r) -j\omega A(r)$

where $A$ is the magnetic [vector potential](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Magnetic_vector_potential&redirect=no).

I do not know the right way to read it correctly. Now I have two kind of analysis for that equation:

**1)** I have always seen this equation in this way: the electric field is determined both by the electrostatic potential $Phi(r)$ (which is bound to the charge distribution in space) and by the time - variation of $A(r)$ (which takes into account of the Faraday Laws).
If this analysis is correct, if I want to evaluate the voltage between the observation point and a reference point, I'll use the following equation:

$V(r)= -\int E(r)\cdot dr = \Phi(r) -j\omega \int A(r)\cdot dr $

If we are in electrostatics, the voltage $V(r)$ is equal to the electrostatic voltage $\Phi(r)$, otherwise it will be different because of the effect of the time - varying magnetic field. So, $V(r)$ is the general voltage, and $\Phi(r)$ the electrostatic voltage.

2) Now I have thought that maybe the previous analysis is not correct. Maybe, $\Phi(r)$ may express the general voltage (which, in electrostatics will be the electrostatic voltage, and in electrodynamics the electrodynamic voltages) and the previous equation may be seen in this way:

$\nabla \Phi(r) = -E(r) -j\omega A(r)$

Its meaning will be these: the voltage between a point r and the reference point is determined by the electric field between them (static, if in electrostatics, dynamic if in electrodynamics), which describes the charge distribution in space, and by the time - variations of the magnetic field, according to Faraday Laws.

They are two different views which are in contrast, since in the first one we are saying that $\Phi$ is only the electrostatic voltage (while the voltage is found as the integral of the electrodynamic field), while in the second one we are saying that $\Phi$ is the general voltage, valid also in electrodynamics.

Which is the correct way (and why)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct way to introduce the electric and the vector potentials is:
$$\mathbf{E}=-\nabla\Phi -\frac{\partial \mathbf{A}}{\partial t}, \mathbf{B}=\nabla\times\mathbf{A}.$$ The time derivative is replaced by $i\omega$ only after Fourier transform in time.

Electrostatics, by definition, deals with the time-independent (i.e. static) fields, which is why the term with the time derivative is identically zero.

*Voltage*, by definition, is the difference of the electric potentials, $\Phi$. Note that this is a local concept, which is useful in analyzing circuits, but hardly ever used in electrodynamics.

Comment: So the voltage between two points is in general represented by Phi, and not simply by the integral of E. Correct?